# update to ubuntu 20 from recovery release

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, recovery-mode

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with some problems which cause it not to have internet connection on it. Due to those problem I am currently using the release version of boot recovery, and would like to know how to perform an upgrade to an upper version (such as Ubuntu 20.04). After the upgrade I want it to have my already installed software and   automatically have new release link in boot list when i turn on the PC, and be able to boot to that upgraded system.

My current Ubuntu version is :

```
so@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
so@so-notebook:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-96-generic
so@so-notebook:~$
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ` the release version of boot recovery,`? And why /how doesn't internet work ?

Comment: I am using the recovery version by selecting advanced boot option at starting PC, and the reason is shut downing during update which the internet drivers corrupted and recommended to upgrade to version 20 !